# Batch editing without rebing Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, telerik-grid

We are currently using Telerik MVC Grid and we are using the batch editing.  Everything works fine from updating, paging, sorting, filtering and grouping what I dont understand is that why when you update something the whole data is refreshed (grid is expecting data to work properly).  Is there a property we can set in the telerik grid not to update the whole data (this is so useful if you dont have an add and delete record), it is in client already anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved this by returning a blank model back to the grid and removing the small red arrow by javascript.    So instead of returning

```
return View(new GridModel<MyViewModel>);
```

I return as

```
return new LargeJsonResult
{
    MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue,
    JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    Data = new GridModel<MyViewModel>
    {
        Data = model.MyViewModel
    }
};
```

And that Large JSON Result came from here
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/AJAX/ajaxmapdataconnector/DataConDemoWebRole/Business/LargeJsonResult.cs.htm

Having said that on my method instead of  the normal ActionResult

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult UpdateSomethingAjax( 
[Bind(Prefix = "inserted")]IEnumerable<MyViewModel> insertedTransactions,
[Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<MyViewModel> updatedTransactions,
[Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<MyViewModel> deletedTransactions)
```

I return it as

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public LargeJsonResult UpdateSomethingAjax(
[Bind(Prefix = "inserted")]IEnumerable<MyViewModel> insertedTransactions,
[Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<MyViewModel> updatedTransactions,
[Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<MyViewModel> deletedTransactions)
```

without the GridAction

Comment: Hey, not sure I follow this.. can you explain how this allows you to edit the grid without rebinding? thanks!